# Cannot upload picture using formdata Asp.net-mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file, input, image-uploading, form-data

I fail to upload pictures using formdata. This is my previous code which was working fine(This is just part of a form):

```
<div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput" style="width: 100%;">
                                                            <div class="fileinput-preview" data-trigger="fileinput" style="margin: 10px 0px;"></div>
                                                            <div>
                                                                <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">              
                                                                    <input type="file" id="filePicture" name="filePicture">
                                                                </span>

                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
```

And this is my Ajax call:

```
$(document).on("click", "#sledBuckSaveBtn", function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    var fd = new FormData(document.getElementById("saveSledBuckForm1"));

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/SledBuck/EditFromSledTestDetails", //url,
        data: fd,

        processData: false, // tell jQuery not to process the data
        contentType: false,
        success: function (result) {

            var title = "Error", msgtype = "error";
            if (result) {
                title = "Success";
                msgtype = "success";

            }

            document.location.reload();

        }
    });
});
```

But my requirement has changed, I need to use Krajee plugin to create an input type:
Here my new code:

```
  <div class="col-md-9">                                                                                                            
<input id="input-@Model.PictureIdList[i]" type="file" class="file" data-show-upload="false" data-show-caption="true" data-input-id="@Model.PictureIdList[i]">

</div>
```

what problem am I facing. I think the reason is I might need to do configuration for Krajee plugin but I'm not sure. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found the answer. I lacked the name of the file input. Just do like this and the file will be regconized:

```
<input id="input-@Model.PictureIdList[i]" name= "fileInput" type="file" class="file" data-show-upload="false" data-show-caption="true" data-input-id="@Model.PictureIdList[i]">
```